# Solving a Set Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is my question

- In a class that has $40$ students, there are $10$ students who could not pass the math exam and $30$ students who passed the english exam.  If there are $6$ students who could not pass the both exam, How many are there students who passed the both exam?

I'm currently  not able to build the correct equation. Might I get help? It seems like a bit confused. That's why I need get help.

Comment: Hint: use the inclusion/exclusion principle.

Comment: @Math_QED What is it, sir? I'm already trying on it. Before using inclusion/exclusion principle, I ought to build the correct equation.

Comment: "group theory" is an incorrect tag; this is a question about sets.

Comment: I believe that It seems better now.

Comment: @Bobtrollsten The inclusion/exclusion principle "gives you the equation," so it would be silly to build the equation before applying the principle.

Comment: Yes but I couldn't plug the values into it. I just know the $6$ is the common. I would say that I need get help for applying the principle.

Comment: @Bobtrollsten Sounds like you need a picture to organize what was given.

Comment: @rschwieb Exactly, you want me to share my picture?

Comment: By " there are 6 students who could not pass the both exam" did you mean that these $6$ students may have passed one, just not both? Or did it mean rather that they didn't pass *either* exam/

Comment: There are 40 students in a class. That's total and there are 6 students who could not pass the both exam, 10 students who could not pass the math exam, 30 students who passed english exam.

Comment: @Bobtrollsten How about you pick from the two alternatives I offered instead of regurgitating the thing I'm asking about...  what you are saying is ambiguous. I guess you do *not* mean that these $6$ students failed both subjects.

Comment: Why you said $66$ students?

Comment: @Bobtrollsten The cut-and-paste duplicated the $6$. I fixed it now.

Comment: So, The thing that confused me is it was given the students who could not pass the math exam and who could pass the english exam. By the way, I could not appy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $4$ types of people:

Let $A$ be the people who passed no exam.

Let $B$ be the people who passed only Math.

Let $C$ be the people who passed only English.

Let $D$ be the people who passed both.

We know $A+B+C+D=40$

We know $A+C=10$

We know $C+D=30$

We know $A=6$.

So this is just a system of equations.

Comment: I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I find a Venn Diagram to always be very helpful for these kinds of questions:

[image]

$A,B,C,D$ are the regions according to Jorge's answer

So we know the following:

[image]

Once you figure out how the '10 people did not pass Math' plays out in the diagram, the rest goes quick.

Comment: I was trying to plug it into venn.

Comment: does the venn diagram help? You get a lot of clumping in this case.

Comment: @JorgeFernández True ... but I think different approaches work better for different people. So maybe for some the diagram is more distracting than helpful, but for others it may be helpful. Personally, I'm a very visual person.  And once you figure out how the '10 people not inside the Passed Math' circle plays out in the diagram, the rest goes quick.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my cute Venn diagram can be useful to somebody :)
$$...$$

[image]