# About Elementary Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a group which occurs by people who play guitar and battery, The value of  who plays guitar is $2$ times of who plays battery. The value of who plays only an instrument is $12$ and who plays the both instrument is $3$.

- How do you find how many person does only play the battery?

I'm so surprised for this question. What would the true equation be?

Comment: Can you please make *some* attempt?  Something like Jorge did for [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498416/solving-a-set-problem)?

Comment: @Bram28 I was going to show my attempt but didn't know where to start.

Comment: OK, but with fleablood's and my hints, can you get the right equations now?

Comment: @Bram28 I'm trying to get it at the moment.

Comment: OK, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I couldn't work out fleasblood's hint. $B = BO + BG$

Comment: does my venn diagram help at all?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, but according to me, It would be $3x-2$, $3$ and $x$.

Comment: What would be?  You have 3 values here ... of what? What in particular is $3x-2$?

Comment: @Bram28 Can you be more clear? I mean venn diagram.

Comment: OK, you have $X$ people playing guitar but not drums. And you have 3 people playing both guitar and drums. So how many people play guitar?

Comment: would it be $3x$? Also I'm getting that $G = GO +12$

Comment: No. $3+x$ play guitar.  And $X+Y=12$ (working with my Venn diagram, right?)

Comment: That's $x$, right?

Comment: Try again .....

Comment: @Bram28 I'm so confused. lmao How about if we use flea's hint?

Comment: It's the exact same idea so let's stick with my diagram. OK, $3+y$ people play drums .. do you see that from the diagram? How you have $3+y$ people within the 'playing drums' circle?

Comment: I'm getting that $B = BO + 3$

Comment: OK, good! And for G?

Comment: @Bram28 Ah, I'm trying to find it out. Any hints?

Comment: And would it be $12 = BO +3$?

Comment: In Bram28's Venn Diagram.  $BO$ is the number of people who only play drums.  That is number of people is $X \setminus (X \cap Y)$.  $GO$ is the size of $Y \setminus (X\cap Y)$. And $BG$ is $|X\cap Y|=3$ We know $|(X \cup Y) \setminus (X \cap Y)| = BO + GO = 12$.  We know $BG=|X\cap Y| =3$ and we know $GO = |Y\setminus (X\cap Y)| = 2*BO =  |X\setminus (X\cap Y)|$.  That's enough to do.  Actually all in all, the Venn diagram, being visual is maybe easier to grasp.  But the are the same idea: Break into distinct components and solve.

Comment: @fleablood Can you show how did you find others? I'm getting that $G = GO +3$ and $B = BO +3$.

Comment: I really need someone's help atm

Comment: @Bram28 Can you show the equations for venn diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down into distinct sets.

There are 1) People who play Battery.  That is set $B$.

There are 2) People who play Guitar.  That is set $G$.

There are 3) People who play Both.  That is set $BG = B \cap G$.  We know $|BG| =3$.

There are 4) People who only play Battery.  That is the set $BO = B \setminus (B \cap G)$ and $BO \cup (B\cap G) = B$ and $BO \cap (B\cap G) = \emptyset$.  So $|BO| = |B| - |BG| = |B| - 3$. and $|BO| + |BG| = |B|= |BO| + 3$.

There are 5) People who only play Guitar  That is the set $GO = G \setminus (B \cap G)$ and $GO \cup (B\cap G) = G$ and $GO \cap (B\cap G) = \emptyset$.  So $|GO| = |G| - |BG| = |G| - 3$. and $|BGO| + |BG| = |G|= |GO| + 3$.

And there are 6) People who only play one instrument.  That is $O = (B \cup G) \setminus (B \cap G) = BO \cup GO$.  We know $BO \cap GO = \emptyset$ and $BO \cup GO = O$ and so we know $|O| = |BO| + |GO|$ and we are told $|O| = 12$.

We are told:

$|BG| = 3$, $|O| = 12$, and $|G| = 2|B|$.

Then its just a matter of solving.

[image: enter image description here[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poOCU.jpg)

$|G| = 2|B|$

$|GO| + |B\cap G| = 2(|BO| + |B\cap G|)$

$|GO| + 3 = 2(|BO| + 3)$ and $|BO| + |GO| = 12$.

Comment: Can you show it a bit more?

Comment: So $G = 2B; GO + BO = 12; BG = 3$.

Comment: I know that $BG = 3$ How did you get others? If you show them on your answer, I would be too happy.

Comment: Can you please show it? How did you find others? I'm getting that $G = GO +3$ and $B = BO +3$.

Comment: I really need your help atm.

Comment: So, How did we find the $BO$ and $GO$?

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Here's another Venn Diagram:

[image]

We know 3 people play both guitar and drums (no one in the English-speaking part of the world plays battery :) )

Say $X$ people play guitar but not battery and $Y$ people play drums but not guitar. Can you now translate the given pieces of information into equations?

Comment: no one in the English-speaking part of the world plays battery :).... Well, my cousin Tony who lives in the garage.... we don't talk about him much....

Comment: @fleablood LOL. OK, so one can play battery ...but not for long :)

Comment: I got $6+2x$ for $G$