# Figuring out the Venn Diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a class that all students might play minimum piano, violin or guitar, there are $24$ students. In this class, the students who might play violin is equal to $2$ times of the students who might only play guitar.

- If there are $9$ students who might play piano but not violin, how many students who might play violin are there?

I'm confused by this question. How do we figure out the venn diagram?

Regards

Comment: How does this vary from an earlier posted question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498557/about-elementary-set-theory)?  By the way, in both posts the unusual phrase "*I'm surprised for this question*" appears, implying that you might be the same user.  That phrase is generally never used in English.  A more common phrase which seems to be what you are intending would be "I'm *confused by* this question."

Comment: @JMoravitz Elementary, Doctor Watson LOL!

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I just want to solve it with better way. That's why I've posted it.

Comment: If anyone takes a look, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

---

By what is given, we get -

$$\sum_{i=i}^7 r(i)=24$$

$$r(2) + r(4) + r(5) + r(7) =  2\times r(3)$$

$$r(1) + r(6) = 9$$

---

Now, what you need to find, i.e, $r(V) = r(2)+r(4)+r(5)+r(7)$ can be done by playing with the three equations.

---

Adding second and third equations, we get

$$r(1) + r(2) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  2\times r(3) + 9$$

Now, adding $r(3)$ on both sides,

$$r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  3\times r(3) + 9$$

LHS becomes equal to the first equation, and so

$$\sum_{i=i}^7 r(i) = 3\times r(3) + 9$$

$$24 = 3\times r(3) + 9$$

$$3\times r(3) = 15$$

$$r(3) = 5$$

Now, put this value in second equation, we get

$$r(2) + r(4) + r(5) + r(7) =  2\times r(3) = 2\times 5 = 10$$

which is what is required. ($r(V)$)

Comment: What do you mean by $r(V)$?

Comment: @Korrigi I just used $r(V)$ to represent the number of students that play the violin in totality.

Comment: However, it seems like $10$ who might play the violin. Also I was wondering how you found the true values while applying the venn diagram.

Comment: @Korrigi Yes. That's correct. I just named it so like that so it's easier to get to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: Did you build the equation before drawing the venn diagram?

Comment: @Korrigi Firstly, I made the Venn diagram, then I named the regions. And then, from it, it equations.

Comment: I can't make the venn diagram :/ that's why I cannot solve these questions.

Comment: Also I couldn't get the equation. Might you be more clear?

Comment: @Korrigi First equation so says that the number of students that lie in all the 7 regions is 24.

Comment: @Korrigi The second one says the students that play the violin ($r(v)$) ($r(2)+r(4)+r(5)+r(7)$ is 2 times the students that **only** play the guitar ($r(3)$).

Comment: @Korrigi The third one says that 9 students play the piano but not the violin (($r(1)+r(4)+r(6)+r(7))-($r(4)+r(7)=r(1)+r(6)=9$).

Comment: @Korrigi And don't worry. Just keep practicing and read about Set Theory. Then I'm sure you'll be able to figure out these kinds of questions.

Comment: Oh, did you build the equations by regions? so you say that you didn't use the values.

Comment: @Korrigi Yes. I built them according to the regions they belonged to.

Comment: How did we arrive at $10$?

Comment: @Korrigi Yes, you can use this method. This simplifies it a bit by naming. But, formally, the union and intersection way is used. Like, $r(7)=r(V \cap P\cap G)$.

Comment: I don't see any values there. it doesn't make any sense. I got what you are trying to mean. However, there's no values there. How do we arrive at $10$ then?

Comment: @Korrigi I have updated my answer and added the arrival at $10$.

Comment: You are great! It seems so useful for my exams.

Comment: @Korrigi All the best for your exams! Keep practicing and you'll be able to ace it.

Comment: However, I'm not advanced that much. So, we don't know what sum means. First time I've seen these terms.

Comment: $r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  3\times r(3) + 9$ What happened to $2$ here? Why isn't it $2\times r(3) +9$?

Comment: @Korrigi $r(3)$ was added to both the sides.

Comment: Why isn't it $2\times r(3) +9$? It ought to be it. it's already added to the right side. I mean this part $3\times$ What happened to $2\times$ there?

Comment: Wait, I got it :D This method seems very very very useful!

Comment: @Korrigi That's great! I like this method too. Works well with most sets of questions.

Comment: Can we apply this with two sets as well? <3

Comment: @Korrigi Yes, it'll work with any number of sets.

Comment: What a great you are! I didn't have any hope till this time but now I'm thinking that it's too easy!

Comment: Also can we give any numbers instead of them? like $r(1)$ instead of $r(2)$?

Comment: @Korrigi You can give any numbers or even alphabets you like. Anything symbolical.

Comment: @Korrigi If I did help, can you do me some good by upvoting my answer? I'll get to 500. :P

Comment: I have to get 2 repulation more to vote your question. Vote my answer +1. also you saved my life lmao.

Comment: Also can you explain me the part of adding $r(3)$ the both side? Why that $2$ gone?

Comment: @Korrigi Oh hah. Right. It's alright anyway. No worries.

Comment: Why that $2$ gone and why did you add $r(3)$? If you can explain this, I'd be too happy.

Comment: I mean this part $r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  3\times r(3) + 9$

Comment: @Korrigi

$$r(1) + r(2) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  2\times r(3) + 9$$

Now, adding $r(3)$ on both sides,

$$(r(1) + r(2) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)) + r(3)=  (2\times r(3) + 9) + r(3)$$

$$r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  3\times r(3) + 9$$

Comment: I added $r(3)$ by looking at the first equation. I just needed to somehow make it similar to it. And I did that by adding $r(3)$ and that way, the first equation could come into play.

Comment: You say that we ought to add $r(3)$ to the left side. By the way, we added it to make it equal. However, I still didn't get why that $2$ gone from the right side.

Comment: @Korrigi No no. We add it to both sides otherwise LHS=RHS won't hold.

Comment: I mean that. We needed $r(3)$ to make it equal. However, I couldn't get why that $2$ gone on the right side.

Comment: @Korrigi Because $2 \times r(3)+r(3)=3 \times r(3)$ just like $2x+x=3x$. It gets added up. That's why.

Comment: @Korrigi Ignore the $\times$ symbol if that creates confusion.

Comment: I just didn't get this part $r(1) + r(2) + r(4) + r(5) + r(6)  + r(7)=  2\times r(3) + 9$ Can you update it? $\times$ is useful. No worries.

Comment: @Korrigi Second and third equations were added to get there.

Comment: I got why we added $r(3)$. we needed to $r(3)$ to make the both sides equal. But the problem is on right side. $ 2\times r(3) + 9$ becomes $ 3\times r(3) + 9$

Comment: @Korrigi Ponder over it. Set theory is interesting but gets frustrating at times. Take a break and get at it with a fresh mind.

Comment: Thanks anyways. =)

Answer (score 0):

Using the venn diagram above:

r(3) = 5

r(6)+r(1) = 9

r(2)+r(4)+r(5)+r(7) = 10

10 students play violin (those students may also play another instrument)